# C# Bitmap Invalid Parameter

Tags: c#, bitmap, azure-blob-storage, filestream, parallel.foreach

Here is what I am trying to do: Take a folder full of images, perform an optimization on them, and store them in the same file.

I get the error:

```
System.ArgumentException
  Message = Parameter is not valid.
```

From line:

```
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(image))
```

I think this has something to do with the file being open, and blocking access but I'm not sure. I know for a fact that the filepath I'm using is correct, and that it is a folder filled with images. Can anyone help me?

```
 string[] folder = Directory.GetFiles(GetSourceDirectory());

        Parallel.ForEach(folder, (file) =>
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                var image = fileStream.Name;
                Console.WriteLine(image);
                Console.ReadLine();
                using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(image))
                {
                    using (var quantized = quantizer.QuantizeImage(bitmap, 1, 1))
                    {
                        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileStream.Name);
                        try
                        {
                            quantized.Save(fileStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                        }
                        catch (ArgumentException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            throw;
                        }

                        blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream).Wait();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why not open the file, create a new file, process each entry from the old file and place in the new file, and when done rename or delete the old file and rename the new file to the old file name?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the filestream to read and write at the same time.

If you change the File.Open to

using (var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))

it will allow you to do

using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(image))

But then obviously you will come unstuck later when you try to write using the fileStream variable.

So I think you will have to change it so you don't have the nested using statements.

Answer (score 0):

FileStream.Name gives you the file name only, like "image.jpg", have you tried **using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(fileStream))**?